# Facebook share dialog - Invalid URL Error

Tags: facebook

I have created app in Facebook developer account, I have set the site URL: http://www.xxxxxxx.com

If I open the page from www.xxxxxxx.com, then it works perfectly.

If I open the page from xxxxxxx.com, then it produces the following error:

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191

API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application
```

How should I specify my URL in my app to avoid this error?

Comment: I suggest that you try making the redirect url same as link url. So, if your link is www... then your redirect url should be www., and the other way around, if your link is without www.. then your redirect url should be without www...

Answer (score 0):

You can set URLs in the settings of your app on facebook. Add xxxxxxx.com to the form field to make it work (additionally to the www.xxxxxxx.com).
You can only use URLs that are owned / set up, correctly.